# How to get value from java class and map it to select statement in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am setting value for- planValue in my java class- DetailsForm. I need to get that property value in the jsp. How will i get it ? I am using same name as planValue as in java here in jsp.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Also, [have you tried anything?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried document.form.planValue.value to get the value. it is not working. i need the value of planValue that is being set in the bean class.

Comment: Can you please include your code to give a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: First decide if you're talking about Java or JavaScript. These are two different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException         {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    performTask(request, response);
}

public void performTask(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {               //create your object
            DetailsForm detailsForm = new DetailsForm();
            //set planValue
            detailsForm.setPlanValue("some plan value");
            //set your object as attribute and use forward
    request.setAttribute("detailsForm", detailsForm);
            //relative path to your JSP
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/some.jsp").forward(request,
            response);

}
```

And your some.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Some JSP
</title>
<head>
<body>
${detailsForm.plainValue}
</body>
</html>
```

And you need to have getter method for plainValue in DetailsForm class.